# How to get Date Value from array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary

I want to store the `date` in a separate array…..How to do this???Am getting confused….Pls help me….

```
(
    {
    "2015-03-27" =         {
        amount = 13086;
        date = "2015-03-26 18:30:00 +0000";
        "date-day" = 27;
        "date-month" = Mar;
        "date-year" = 2015;
        units = 2160;
    };
},
    {
    "2015-08-03" =         {
        amount = 18300;
        date = "2015-08-02 18:30:00 +0000";
        "date-day" = 03;
        "date-month" = Aug;
        "date-year" = 2015;
        units = 2950;
    };
},
)
```

Comment: That data structure is screwed and has ruined my perfect answer.

Comment: can you add some more code it is some diffuclict to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is in Array (which is collection of Dictionary)

So, first get Dictionary from Array & then add key of particular dictionary in to new Array (which is resulted array of Dates)

Try this:

```
NSArray *arrData;

NSMutableArray *arrDates = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *dict in arrData) {
    
    [arrDates addObject:[[dict allKeys] firstObject]];
}

NSLog(@"Dates :: %@", arrDates);
```

Comment: thanks.But If i want Units and amount for the respective Date means,How to get....Its not allowing`valueForKey`....

Comment: @Raghunath : For Units & amount, you can access by "[dict valueForKey:@"units"];"

Comment: And for units & amount in respective dates, you can take inner Dictionary. Or I suggest, manage all things with NSObject class. It would be better & maintained with structured data

Comment: Do not use `valueForKey:` on a dictionary unless you really mean (and need) the KVC method. Use `objectForKey:` or key subscripting.

Answer (score 0):

The outer object is an array, item 0 contains the two dictionaries.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = array[0];
```

Then enumerate the dictionary and extract the `date` values

```
NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
   [dates addObject: dictionary[key][@"date"]];
}
```